# Need to split an integer and add it with itself

Tags: c

So, my basic problem is that I'm trying to write a program for a small project I'm working on for fun.

Basically, my issue is this: I need to take user input, as an int, say 15, then manipulate the number so that it returns the result of 1 + 5, being 6. Or for another example say the number is 29, will give you 2 + 9 = 11, which would then need to be reduced down again to 1 + 1 = 2. That could probably be handled easily, but I'm stuck on how to actually split the int apart without having to take the numbers in one by one. I guess it's possible to with RegEx, but I was looking for a more efficient method.

Comment: Looks like a Project Euler problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample code is here:

```
int sum_of_digits(int n)
{
    if(n < 10)
    {
        return n;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    while( n > 0)
    {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum_of_digits(sum);
}

int main()
{
    int n1 = sum_of_digits(29);
    int n2 = sum_of_digits(15);
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, reading this over it's reminded me that this is really close to what I used back when I first had this going a while back.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a particularly good job for a regex. The usual way would be to get individual digits as the remainder after dividing by 10.

Answer (score 0):

In *C*, this would do the trick for two digits:

```
digit_sum = my_int%10 + my_int/10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest way here is to use `/` (divide) and `%` (modulus) operators to traverse your integer.

```
int base = 15;
int acum = 0;
while (base > 0) {
    acum = acum + (base % 10);
    base = base / 10;
};

// At this point, base = 0 and acum = 6
// if acum > 10, then assign it to base and start again.
```

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! I had done it a long, long time ago and just couldn't remember how.